# Hibernate: Mapping entity as list to two or more another entities

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, entity

```
@Entity
class Item {
  ...
}

@Entity
class Character {
  ...
  @OneToMany
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    ...
  }
}

@Entity
class Bank {
  ...
  @OneToMany
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to have one table for an Item entities with DTYPE field {Characters,Bank} and ID filed. How can I do such kind of mapping? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found solution - `@WhereJoinTable`.

```
@Entity
class Item {
  ...
}

@Entity
class Character {
  ...
  @OneToMany
  ..
  @WhereJoinTable(clause="DTYPE = 'Character'")
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    ...
  }
}

@Entity
class Bank {
  ...
  @OneToMany
  ..
  @WhereJoinTable(clause="DTYPE = 'Bank'")
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Of course don't forget about `@JoinTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@DiscriminatorColumn()`
Read about it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168) (p. 2.2.4.2)

Comment: I also believe I should use `@DiscriminatorColumn`, but I didn't find any example of how can I use it for mapping an entity as `@OneToMany` in a few places.